# Linking two java activty's with button bug! "Android Studio"

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm quite new to Java could you please show where i've gone wrong would be much appreciated many thanks! I want to Link two java activty's with button when presed

---

```
package com.example.matt.androidui;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
```

Called at the top of activty.

Code i'm having trouble with seems to be something up!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener) {

    public void onClick (View v){

        Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivity2Activity.class);
        startActivityForResult(kntent, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Button Code ends here!

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

---

Comment: Fix the format please

Comment: And after you fix the format, post the logcat.

Comment: What's this: `noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement`? Is that supposed to be a comment?

Comment: Should be fixed now apology messes up the format up when you paste it in

Comment: yes it is @Voicu it said I had to much code so removed the // from the comments to compensate

Comment: `startActivityForResult(kntent, 0);` This should be compilation error, unless you actually typed (not copy pasted) this code in here.

Comment: @MattTheCodeMan you forgot to mention what actually your question is.

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is not actually working? Have you added "MainActivity2Activity" to your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start second activity by pressing button then simply do this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful got some other things the IDE is underlining have you got any idea's I can upload a screenshot if that helps

Comment: @MattTheCodeMan upload a screenshot somewhere and post a link here

Comment: My mate helped me in the end thanks so much for you help you have been amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

@MattTheCodeMan 
If you want to start a second activity by pressing a button then write this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), MainActivity2Activity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new in Android maybe is good start with the navigation edition in android studio, [LOOK THIS LINK](http://tools.android.com/navigation-editor)